# What's wrong with this CSS?

Tags: css

I tested the code in three browsers and it worked perfectly well

**However**, when I viewed it from another computer with slightly lower quality graphics the only thing that worked was the normal text colours and nothing else...

What's wrong with the code?

```
body {          
    background: #CCCCCC;            
}

td {            
    font-family: Arial;         
}

table.border {          
    background: #0000FF;            
}

.thead {            
    background: #0000FF;
    color: #FFFFFF;         
}

.thead a {          
    color: #00FFFF;             
}

.thead a:hover {            
    color: #FF0000;             
}

.tbody {            
    background: #FFFFFF;
    color: #000000;         
}

a {         
    color: #0000FF;         
}

a:hover {           
    color: #FF0000;         
}

input,textarea {            
    background: #FFFFFF;
    border: solid 1px #0000FF;
    color: #0000FF;         
}

input.button {          
    background: #FFFFFF;
    border: solid 1px #0000FF;
    color: #0000FF;         
}
```

Comment: What browser on the second computer? Are there any add-ons installed in it?

Comment: I think its Internet Explorer 7, it has no add ons because its a public computer

Comment: The W3C CSS Validator has no problems with this CSS. As a tip: if you define any colour, you should define all colours. This may be easiest to do with a reset stylesheet.

Comment: Oh good idea, thanks I'll try it
It won't have any visible effect though because all the text is inside tables, but I'll try it to see if it fixes the problem

Answer (score 2):

My guess would be that the browser is reading the CSS property and expecting the other values.
You should try replacing

```
background
```

with

```
background-color
```

Comment: I already tried that over a web-based FTP client on the other computers, unfortunately it didn't work =(

Comment: Still it is bad practice to not fill in all of the values for any CSS property.

Comment: Okay I've changed it, I'm not sure if it will work yet though

Answer (score 2):

`border` should be in the order `1px solid #0000FF`.

I would write `background-color`, but `background` should also work.

Comment: Thanks =) I've fixed the error
I won't find out if it works until the next time I use the other computers, but thanks

Answer (score 1):

Is the browser version number on this computer different than other computers you tested on?  And, what do you mean by "lower quality graphics"?  The browser has different graphics settings (which could certainly cause this), or the monitor/videoCard is old?

Comment: I think the other one is Internet Explorer 7 (I tested it on Google Chrome, Firefox and Internet Explorer 8) but, CSS on other sites seem to work fine

Answer (score 1):

they possibly fall out side of the "web safe" colours. see here:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_colors

Comment: I'm sure they're all web safe
What I mean is, it doesn't show the colours at all, it just shows the default white everywhere like theres no CSS

Comment: ooh, good point; older browser might have that problem.  These are web-safe though.  These colors are actually web-safe though, made up of 00's and FF's.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure it's an issue with this CSS, and not an issue with how you link to the style sheet or with the style sheet?

I know that some browsers (Firefox etc) are a little more forgiving when it comes to issues like this...

Comment: The code I used was:

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/default.css" />

Answer (score 0):

you can use `border: solid 1px #0000FF;`. it's correct too, maybe the file its not included in your HTML file, upload the full files, so we can help